# How to associate data from a different factory?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 Models to be associated. It called `Menu` and `Page`. The relation between each is something like this:

> Each `Menu` has one `Page`
>
> Each `Page` belongs to a `Menu`

I have created a seeder that looks like this:

```php
<?php

use App\App;
use App\Component;
use App\Menu;
use App\Page;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $tester = new User();
        $tester->name = "Tester";
        $tester->email = "test@appbuilder.com";
        $tester->password = bcrypt('password');
        $tester->save();

        // Create 5 apps for each user
        $tester->apps()->saveMany(factory(App::class, 5)->make())->each(function ($app) {

            // Create 5 menus for each app
            $app->menus()->saveMany(factory(Menu::class, 5)->make());

            // Create 5 pages for each app
            $app->pages()->saveMany(factory(Page::class, 5)->make())->each(function ($page) {
                $page->components()->saveMany(factory(Component::class, 5)->make()); // Create 5 components for each page
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I want to associate each page created by its factory with the menus. Something like this:

```php
$menu->associate($page);
```

Is it possible? How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subtract the creation logic out and creates them similar to this it should be possible. You have to do it after the last save many, as the model is not created before that.

```
$menus = factory(Menu::class, 5)->make();

$pages = factory(Page::class, 5)->make();

...

$menus->each(function ($menu) use ($pages) {
    $pages->each(function ($page)  use ($menu) {
        $page->associate($menu);
    });
});
```

Comment: Excuse me @mrhn, I would like to thank for your help before. I have implemented it in my code and I just realize that it's only associates the last data, not all of each instances. Could you please help me with this? Please take a look at the data taken from `php artisan tinker` command [here](https://pastebin.com/ri9MbFuN). I really confused with how the factories works inside the seeder. :(

Comment: The logic seems ok, it could be you dont have the fresh version of the object since it is done inverse, try to do $menu->associate($page) instead? and is the database correct?

Comment: I'm sure there is no fault on the database. Here, I have created a new question and provides the data I get from that logic, maybe you can help me once again.. Please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58761827/laravel-factories-association-only-associates-the-last-data-how-to-fix-this