# Laravel factories association only associates the last data. How to fix this?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 models that needs to be associated once the data was created. I already asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58742894/how-to-associate-data-from-a-different-factory) and got the answer. I implemented it and made some modification because it doesn't associate the data correctly. Now I have problem with the association. It is only associated on the last data.

What I'm expecting is all the data created from the factory is associated to each other.

When I do `php artisan tinker` and run `App\App::first()->load('menus', 'menus.page')` command, it does not give me the correct data. Please take a look at the result [here](https://pastebin.com/ri9MbFuN).

As you can see, the right data shown only on the last object. The rest is `null`. How can I fix this? Please take a look at my seeder file below, do I made any mistake?

```php
<?php

use App\App;
use App\Component;
use App\Menu;
use App\Page;
use App\Role;
use App\Submenu;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $superadmin = Role::whereName('superadmin')->first();

        $tester = new User();
        $tester->name = "Tester";
        $tester->email = "test@appbuilder.com";
        $tester->password = bcrypt('password');
        $tester->save();

        $tester->roles()->attach($superadmin);

        // Create 5 apps for each user
        $tester->apps()->saveMany(factory(App::class, 5)->make())->each(function ($app) {
            $menus = factory(Menu::class, 5)->make();
            $pages = factory(Page::class, 5)->make();

            // Create 5 menus for each app and 5 submenus for each menu
            $app->menus()->saveMany($menus)->each(function ($menu) use ($pages) {
                // Associate page with each menu
                $pages->each(function ($page) use ($menu) {
                    $page->menu()->associate($menu);
                });

                // Create 5 submenus for each menu
                $menu->submenus()->saveMany(factory(Submenu::class, 5)->make())->each(function ($submenu) use ($pages) {
                    // Associate page with each submenu
                    $pages->each(function ($page) use ($submenu) {
                        $page->submenu()->associate($submenu);
                    });
                });
            });

            // Create 5 pages for each app and 5 components for each page
            $app->pages()->saveMany($pages)->each(function ($page) {
                $page->components()->saveMany(factory(Component::class, 5)->make());
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**Update**

Here is my model files, please take a look:

`App.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class App extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should not be mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    /**
     * Each app belongs to a user.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsTo
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    /**
     * Each app has many pages.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\HasMany
     */
    public function pages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Page::class);
    }

    /**
     * Each app has many menus.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\HasMany
     */
    public function menus()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Menu::class);
    }
}
```

`Menu.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Menu extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should not be mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    /**
     * Each menu belongs to a app.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsTo
     */
    public function app()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App::class);
    }

    /**
     * Each menu has one page.
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\HasOne
     */
    public function page()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Page::class);
    }

    /**
     * Each menu has many submenus.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\HasMany
     */
    public function submenus()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Submenu::class);
    }

    /**
     * Each menu belongs to many roles.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
}
```

`Page.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Page extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should not be mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    /**
     * Each page belongs to an app.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsTo
     */
    public function app()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App::class);
    }

    /**
     * Each page has many components.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\HasMany
     */
    public function components()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Component::class);
    }

    /**
     * Each page belongs to a menu.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsTo
     */
    public function menu()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Menu::class);
    }

    /**
     * Each page belongs to a submenu.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsTo
     */
    public function submenu()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Submenu::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got a couple of people to look at this, everything seems fine, but before you run your command is the database clean, since you do App\App::first()->load('menus', 'menus.page')  it will load the first and i'm afraid it could be in a bad state when you load the first one.

Comment: I don't think so.. I take the first just to make it simple to read when I paste it. It does the same thing when I run `App\App::all()->load('menus', 'menus.page);`. The rest of the page object is `null` except the last one.

Comment: I did a fresh `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` command and quit the tinker for several times too, but still having the same result

Comment: When you do `$pages->each(function ($page) use ($menu) {$page->menu()->associate($menu); });` you associate each pages to the same menu. Consequently only the last page will be associated to the menus and only the last menu will have the last page since the page can have only one menu.

Comment: I agree, I've been thinking about that for a long time, but I still can't find the right solution for that problem.

Comment: What about something like that `$app->menus()->saveMany($menus)->each(function ($menu, $key) use ($pages) { $pages[$key]->menu()->associate($menu);  });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in fact you DID make a mistake. By looping through every page inside the menu loop. So in the first run every page would be associated the the first menu entry. In the second run every page with the second menu entry and so on. With finally leading to the fact, that every page is associated with the last menu entry.

To keep the structure like you have one could do something like this:

```
        $tester = new \App\User();
    $tester->name = "Tester";
    $tester->email = "test@appbuilder.com";
    $tester->password = bcrypt('password');
    $tester->save();


    // Create 5 apps for each user
    $tester->apps()->saveMany(factory(\App\App::class, 5)->make())->each(function ($app) {
        $menus = factory(\App\Menu::class, 5)->make();
        $pages = factory(\App\Page::class, 5)->make();

        $pagesIterator = $pages->getIterator();

        // Create 5 menus for each app and 5 submenus for each menu
        $app->menus()->saveMany($menus)->each(function ($menu) use ($pagesIterator) {

            $page = current($pagesIterator);
            $page->menu()->associate($menu);

            // Create 5 submenus for each menu
            $menu->submenus()->saveMany(factory(\App\Submenu::class, 5)->make())->each(function ($submenu) use ($page) {
                // Associate page with each submenu
                $page->submenu()->associate($submenu);
            });

            next($pagesIterator);
        });

        // Create 5 pages for each app and 5 components for each page
        $app->pages()->saveMany($pages)->each(function ($page) {
            $page->components()->saveMany(factory(\App\Component::class, 5)->make());
        });

    });
```

So we just get the next page from the collection inside the loop via an iterator and associate each menu with the next page from the collection. (Note that you would need to create more pages, if you want every submenu have a different page associated...)

Off topic:

```
$page->menu()->associate($menu);
```

normally needs a `$page->save()` followed by, as the associate() method does not save automatically. In your case the $pages get persisted to database by calling `$app->pages()->saveMany($pages)` at the end.

Comment: thank you for the answer, for this very useful information. it works as I expected and finally I learned a new thing from this today.

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing to share your source code for the models? I think that would be helpful, coz I'm not quite sure what relations is `$tester->apps()` returning, is it `belongsToMany` or `hasMany` etc...

and reading `saveMany's` source code in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany`:

```
   /**
     * Save an array of new models and attach them to the parent model.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Collection|array  $models
     * @param  array  $pivotAttributes
     * @return array
     */
    public function saveMany($models, array $pivotAttributes = [])
    {
        foreach ($models as $key => $model) {
            $this->save($model, (array) ($pivotAttributes[$key] ?? []), false);
        }

        $this->touchIfTouching();

        return $models;
    }
```

not sure if your getting an `array` or a `collection`, so this might be a case of a loop that wasn't executed, might as well do a `foreach loop` on `saveMany's` return value ie:

```
$savedModels = $tester->apps()->saveMany(factory(App::class, 5)->make());

// You can be sure that $model is an instance of `Model`
foreach($saveModels as $model){
// Do the logic here instead
}
```

anyway I can't dig deeper with the current info I have.

Comment: Anyway, I already did your suggestion using foreach and still having the same result

Comment: Cool, I'll have a go at it